# Escaping the dot character in tr -dc

Tags: tr

I'm trying to rename files using `tr`. The following command nearly works:

```
for file in ./*; do mv -v "$file" $(echo "$file" | tr ' []' '-' | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9_-' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'); done
```

However, the command also strips dot characters. So, this file:

> St Nicholas' church from NE [1235] 1936-08-01.jpg

becomes

> st-nicholas-church-from-ne--1235--1936-08-01jpg

I've tried various ways to escape the dot, for instance using `tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9\._-'` and `tr -dc "A-Za-z0-9\._-"`

The result invariably is that every character gets deleted. So my question, how to properly escape dot character in `tr -dc`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the dot. `tr` doesn't use regular expressions.

Comment: @Kusalananda Hmmm, but if I don't escape the dot everything is deleted as well.

Comment: Not when I try it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the dot in the "allowed characters" set. Also add the `/` character (part of the path).

```
for f in ./*; do
  new_f="$( printf "%s" "$f" | tr ' []' '-' | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9_./-' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
  printf "Would move '%s' to '%s'\n" "$f" "$new_f"
done
```

This results in

```
Would move './St Nicholas' church from NE [1235] 1936-08-01.jpg' to './st-nicholas-church-from-ne--1235--1936-08-01.jpg'
```

Comment: Ah, yes - adding the '/' that did the trick! Never crossed my mind. Thanks a million.

Comment: @rkhff Yes, I wasn't quite sure what you meant by "deleted". You either meant that the filename became empty, or that the files appeared to be deleted. In the second case, have a look to see if you now have a bunch of "hidden" files laying around (`ls -a`) whose filenames begin with a dot.

Comment: Yep, lots of dot files in the directory - so the files appeared to have been deleted.

Comment: @rkhff Just "appears" to have been deleted. They were renamed with the leading part of the path (`./`) changed to `.`.